# How to pass code from fragment to viewmodel

Tags: java, mvvm

I have questions about how to pass a fagment code to the viewmodel, I want to pass input validation methods that are related to the registration screen This method is related to password validation, if the password does not meet all the requirements, display a component with the characteristics of how the password should be If the password was complying with the characteristics, the component with the characteristics of what the password should be will be hidden I want to know how to pass valid_Password() and input Password() function to viewmodel

```
if(password.length <8){
isChar = true
binding.txtConditionsPassword.visibility = View.VISIBLE 
           
binding.txtpasswordNotCharacteristics.visibility = View.VISIBLE 
           
binding.linearLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE    
        
binding.txtpasswordFeature.visibility = View.GONE
            
binding.txtMinimumCharacters.setTextColor(Color.RED) 
           
binding.ImgCloseMinimumCharacters.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            
binding.ImgCheckMinimumCharacters.visibility = View.GONE
        
} else {
            
isChar = false
            
binding.txtMinimumCharacters.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
            
binding.ImgCheckMinimumCharacters.visibility = View.VISIBLE
           
 binding.ImgCloseMinimumCharacters.visibility = View.GONE
        
}
```